# Problem installing Tensorflow in AWS EC2 instance

Tags: python, tensorflow, amazon-ec2

I need TensorFlow to execute a python script, when installing it, either using

- pip3 install TensorFlow
- pip3 install --upgrade TensorFlow

Or any other alternative it just doesn't work.

[image: Problem]

I don't know if its related, but every time I try to install it, the *killed* message appears at the end.

Note: the *--trusted-host* option was from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61262224/unable-to-install-tensorflow-in-python-virtual-environment)

thanks in advance.

Comment: You are using an instance with very little RAM, so little that even running pip goes out of memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
pip3 install tensorflow-cpu
```